# Why is focusout event triggered when clicking on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, onfocus, focusout

I have a div which I use as a textbox

```
<div class="field-wrapper">
     Name
     <div id="name" class="name" tabindex="-1">
         Enter a name
     </div>
```

And I want to detect focus and unfocus events of the div textbox.

```
$('.name').focus(function() {
    console.log("focused")
});

$('.name').focusout(function() {
    console.log("unfocused");
});
```

But, whenever I click on the div, both the `focus` and the `focusout` events are triggered. Why is that so?

Comment: try **blur** instead of focusout

Comment: The problem still persist. And blur is not triggered when the element loses focus.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working fine. Here is the fiddle assuming you are wrapping it inside some kind of dom ready:

```
$(function(){
   $('.name').focus(function() {
    console.log("focused")
   });

  $('.name').focusout(function() {
    console.log("unfocused");
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BkJLn/

Answer (score 0):

Once I disabled jEditable which was applied to the div element, the problem was gone. So it seems that jEditable is somehow calling the `focusout` event when the element is focused.

That being said, my main purpose of using `focus` and `focusout` was to capture any changes the user had entered, which I should do using jeditable's functions.